# Adding Model field from django views

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework with pandas to make an api and my models.py file looks like this

```
class Health(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    Age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Weight = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Height = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Sugar = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

and my views.py file looks like this

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_view(request,id):
    qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id)
    df = read_frame(qs)
    df['x-Mean'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean())
    df['1.96*std'] = 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['Outlier'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean()) > 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['BMI'] = df['Weight']/(df['Height']/100)**2
    a = df.fillna(0)
    a = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')
    return Response(a)
```

As you can see that i have no model field named BMI as I am creating it in my views using pandas dataframe and I want to save the field and it's corresponding data in my django database from django views. can anyone help me to achieve this task or suggest an appropriate way to do this.

Comment: If you know that you have to calculate `BMI` and always save it, why not add the field beforehand and instead of calculating in the view, you could calculate in the `save` method by overriding it in the model.

Comment: @AKS can u help me in correcting my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by AKS you need to create field for BMI in django models then updat e that field in your views using save.
Here is how you do it:

```
class Health(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    Age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Weight = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Height = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Sugar = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    BMI =  models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

In your views do this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_view(request,id):
    qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id)
    df = read_frame(qs)
    df['x-Mean'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean())
    df['1.96*std'] = 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['Outlier'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean()) > 1.96*df['Age'].std()
    df['BMI'] = df['Weight']/(df['Height']/100)**2

    # once the BMI is caluculated update the DB row with the value
    qs.BMI = df['BMI']
    qs.save()


    a = df.fillna(0)
    a = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')

    return Response(a)
```

Try this:

view function:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_view(request,id):
    qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id)
    l = len(qs)

    if l>0:
        for x in qs:
            df = read_frame(x)
            df['x-Mean'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean())
            df['1.96*std'] = 1.96*df['Age'].std()
            df['Outlier'] = abs(df['Age'] - df['Age'].mean()) > 1.96*df['Age'].std()
            df['BMI'] = df['Weight']/(df['Height']/100)**2


            # once the BMI is caluculated update the DB row with the value
            x.BMI = df['BMI']
            x.save()

            a = df.fillna(0)
            a = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')


    else:
        print "no rows exists for the query "
```

Hope this was useful.

Comment: I am getting the following error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: I used qs.update() but still nothing is saved in my database

Comment: Try using this query :  qs = Health.objects.get(id = id)

Comment: qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id) , filter is used to get multiple rows from db. if u want to get multiple rows use this and loop through the objects and modify each of them.  But if u want to query only one row you should use qs = Health.objects.get(id = id)

Comment: gettin an error message 'Health' object has no attribute '_iterable_class'

Comment: Are you trying to update mupltiple rows at a time in your view or update only one row ?

Comment: single row at a time

Comment: read_frame() method will work with filter() method so i have to update multiple rows

Comment: @srk See the update in my answer.  Try to change your view and check.

Comment: i have done it using previous code but I would like to thank you for your support.Here is my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def my_view(request,id):
    qs = Health.objects.filter(id = id)
    df = read_frame(qs)
    df['x-Mean'] = abs(df['age'] - df['age'].mean())
    df['1.96*std'] = 1.96*df['age'].std()
    df['outlier'] = abs(df['age'] - df['age'].mean()) > 1.96*df['age'].std()
    df['bmi'] = df['weight']/(df['height']/100)**2
    for q in qs:
        q.bmi = df['bmi'][0]
        q.save()
    a = df.fillna(0)
    a = a.to_dict(orient = 'records')
    return Response(a)
```